# Lost file in Linux with the move command

Tags: linux

I have lost a file while attempting to move it. I accidentally put three periods after the file name when I meant to put two. The command I ran was 'mv file.txt ...'. Ive used the find command to look for it, but I cant seem to track it down. Anyone encountered this before that might know where the file went?

Comment: now do mv ... file.txt

Comment: That command would rename it to "..." in whatever directory you were in.  So if you cd into that directory and do `mv ... ../file.txt` you should be able to get it back.

Comment: `ls -a` shows all files including hidden files (files starting with a `.`

Answer (score 2):

Using the Graphical User Interface, do "view hidden files" on the folder you were in. Either that, or press Ctrl-h (which does the same thing).

Normally, I'd tell you to type ls -la from the terminal, but the syntax coloring of your terminal window may not be smart enough to show those three dots as a normal hidden file.

Comment: Why didn't you just test it? `ls -la` works fine, although `ls -lA` works even better.

Comment: Because I couldn't, I had no idea what terminal emulator he was using.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The terminal emulator shouldn't affect syntax colouring? (Also, are you talking about the `--color=auto` option?)